# c# IWebDriver - Help me onlick to "Đăng nhập" ("Đăng nhập" = "Login")

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

i tried anything i found in google but all that  cant use

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }IWebDriver driver;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://idol.talktv.vn/");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //help me some code
    }
```

```html
<div class="no-login" style="" id="noLoginBox"> <a style="float:left" href="javascript:void(0);"></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="LoginLogicManagement.showForm();" class="dl"><font><font class="">Đăng nhập </font></font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #CACACA"><font><font class="">| </font></font></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://id.zing.vn/v2/register" target="_blank" class="zc" style="cursor: pointer;"><font><font class="">Đăng ký </font></font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

[and a pic for easy look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy57u.png)

Comment: nobody helppppppppp :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the element by XPath. Then click on it. (Right click in Chrome, Inspect, right click on Đăng nhập and copy XPath.

Then:

driver.FindElement(By.XPath......Click();

Good luck

Comment: yah it true, tks friend :x